# Deny service to my JAX-RS service

Tags: java, jax-rs, cdi

What's the best way to deny service to my JAX-RS service?

I need to instantiate a couple of singletons but can't start them using CDIs `@Startup` annotation.
So I was thinking to instantiate them upon initial request to any `POST` or `GET` method. 
Once these beans are instantiated I'll mark the service as available.

Any examples appreciated.

Comment: BTW @Startup is ejb annotation, not CDI one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a session bean is annotated with `@Singleton` and **not** with `@Startup`, the bean is initialized on **first use**, managed by the container. So that's not the way to go.

---

#### Resource in application scope

However, you can have a resource bean in the *application scope*. The resource maintains the *state* as long as the web application runs.

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Path("single")
public class SingleResource {

    private boolean activated;

    @GET
    @Path("activate")
    public Response activate() {
        activated = true;
        return Response.ok("Service Activated", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
                .build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("deactivate")
    public Response deactivate() {
        activated = false;
        return Response.ok("Service Deactivated", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
                .build();
    }

    @GET
    public Response foo() {
        if (activated) {
            return Response.ok("Service Available", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
                    .build();
        } else {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)
                    .entity("Service Unavailable")
                    .type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
                    .build();
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Resource in request scope

If you need that the resource bean lives as long as a single HTTP request-response cycle, in the *request scope*, it is also possible to use a singleton session bean. e.g.:

```
@Singleton
public class SingleBean {

    private boolean activated;

    public boolean isActivated() {
        return activated;
    }

    public void setActivated(boolean activated) {
        this.activated = activated;
    }
}
```

And the resource:

```
@Path("foo")
@Stateless
public class FooResource {

    @EJB
    private SingleBean dummyBean;

    @GET
    @Path("activate")
    public Response activate() {
        dummyBean.setActivated(true);
        return Response.ok("Service Activated", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
                .build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("deactivate")
    public Response deactivate() {
        dummyBean.setActivated(false);
        return Response.ok("Service Deactivated", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
                .build();
    }

    @GET
    public Response foo() {
        if (dummyBean.isActivated()) {
            return Response.ok("Service Available", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
                    .build();
        } else {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)
                    .entity("Service Unavailable")
                    .type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
                    .build();
        }
    }
}
```